# How can I check if there's any number within an input text? (JQuery)

Tags: jquery

I have this input text:

```
<div class="input text col-sm-6 col-xs-12 required">
    <input name="data[Fornecedor][endereco]" placeholder="* Endereço" maxlength="255" type="text" id="FornecedorEndereco" required="required" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

This address field have both letters and digits. How can I check with JQuery if it has a number apart from just text? (I want to display an error message informing the client of the necessity of including an address number)

Comment: For what it's worth, it should be noted that not every real address includes a number (although chances are your problem domain may be restricted enough that it's a valid assumption). https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression

```js
$('#FornecedorEndereco').change(function() {
  var hasDigit = /\d/.test($(this).val());
  console.log(hasDigit);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input text col-sm-6 col-xs-12 required">
  <input name="data[Fornecedor][endereco]" placeholder="* Endereço" maxlength="255" type="text" id="FornecedorEndereco" required="required" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```